# Tableview doesn't show content?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'm trying to show some data on tableview that (e.g first name ,last name ,email etc)
I used the code from oracle documentation is like that :

```
 import javafx.application.Application; import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty; import javafx.collections.FXCollections; import javafx.collections.ObservableList; import javafx.geometry.Insets; import javafx.scene.Group; import javafx.scene.Scene; import javafx.scene.control.Label; import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn; import javafx.scene.control.TableView; import javafx.scene.control.TextField; import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory; import javafx.scene.layout.VBox; import javafx.scene.text.Font; import javafx.stage.Stage; public class TableViewSample extends Application { private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>(); private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList( new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"), new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"), new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"), new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"), new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com") ); public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); } @Override public void start(Stage stage) { Scene scene = new Scene(new Group()); stage.setTitle("Table View Sample"); stage.setWidth(450); stage.setHeight(500); final Label label = new Label("Address Book"); label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20)); table.setEditable(true); TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name"); firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100); firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName")); TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name"); lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100); lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName")); TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email"); emailCol.setMinWidth(200); emailCol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email")); table.setItems(data); table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol); final VBox vbox = new VBox(); vbox.setSpacing(5); vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10)); vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table); ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox); stage.setScene(scene); stage.show(); } public static class Person { private final SimpleStringProperty firstName; private final SimpleStringProperty lastName; private final SimpleStringProperty email; private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) { this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName); this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName); this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email); } public String getFirstName() { return firstName.get(); } public void setFirstName(String fName) { firstName.set(fName); } public String getLastName() { return lastName.get(); } public void setLastName(String fName) { lastName.set(fName); } public String getEmail() { return email.get(); } public void setEmail(String fName) { email.set(fName); } } }
```

I got exception :

Feb 13, 2022 8:21:24 PM javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory getCellDataReflectively
WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'firstName' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@67bfcda1 with provided class type: class application.TableViewSample$Person
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module javafx.base cannot access class application.TableViewSample$Person (in module myTabel) because module myTabel does not open application to javafx.base

Comment: Formatting your code this way is not readable. You can also format the stack trace as code (just indent four spaces) to make it easier to read.

Comment: I added the line ```opens application to javafx.base ``` and it worked ,this problem taked a week and then I solved it with with on line ,thank you very much 

Comment: you would have found it earlier had you read the java doc of PropertyValueFactory ;)

Comment: I don't have java doc ,this is another problem 

Comment: _I don't have java doc_ come on, you must be kidding..trying to use any api without knowing its specification is driving in a very dark wood without any lights on and being utterly drunk .. hint: they are online, do some research to find them

Answer (score 0):

Add the line:

```
opens application to javafx.base
```

to your module-info.Java file.

Study and learn how Java 9 modules work.

Searching for the error message will tell you about it and how to fix it.

Search also for lambda vs PropertyValueFactory. Using lambdas is an alternate way to address your issues.